# angular 4 ngfor parent key with id values

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I want to receive all the values from the UserHardware with all parent keys
The child nodes inside the random generated keys has the structure: `name: Test,desc: test`

[image: Firebase Structure]

My code in the constructor(Component)

```
 this.userHardwareList = db.list('UserHardware/');
this.items = this.userHardwareList.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

In the (template)

```
 <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
 {{item.key}}
</li>
```

Now I am only receiving the value `udwcGxqx50ZtoF8EABoFh8GVet2` (UID)
But I also want the values inside this UID.

I tried:      `{{item.name}}`
but I displays nothing.

When I change the code in the constructor however:

```
this.userHardwareList = db.list('UserHardware/udwcGxqx50ZtoF8EABoFh8GVet2');
```

it works and I can get values and different generated keys by using

```
{{item.name}}` {{item.key}}` {{item.desc}}`
```

How can I make it work when I do not specify the UID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want to do

```
 this.userHardwareList = db.list('UserHardware/');
this.items = this.userHardwareList.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, data:c.payload.val() }));
});
```

then

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
 {{item.key}}
  <ol>
    <li *ngFor="let data of items">
      {{data.name}}{{data.desc}}
    </li>
  <ol>
</li>
```